# How can I get my script to loop?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, watir-webdriver, webautomation

I have it where my script signs in and goes to a browser url, yet when it signs out of the current web page it just sits there and won't restart the loop. How can I get the loop to realize its done and to restart?

```
x = 0

while x <= 5

File.open("yahoo_accounts.txt") do |email|
    email.each do |item|
    email, password = item.chomp.split(',')
    emails << email 
    passwords << password
    emails.zip(passwords) { |name, pass| 
        browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
        browser.goto "url"

    #logs in and does what its suppose to do with the name and pass

        }
    end
    x += 1
    next
end
end
```

When the script is done it just sits at the webpage...I'm trying to get it to go to the beginning again...
You would think it would take each name,pass and go back to the beginning url.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may not be calling `browser.close` appropriately. In my quick mock-up testing, I definitely get weird behaviour if I don't do that. You're also using non-idiomatic Ruby looping. Try this:

```
5.times do 
  File.open("yahoo_accounts.txt") do |email|
    email.each do |item|
      email, password = item.chomp.split(',')
      emails << email 
      passwords << password
      emails.zip(passwords) do |name, pass| 
        browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
        browser.goto "url"

        #logs in and does what its suppose to do with the name and pass

        browser.close
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, if you want the same exact `Watir::Browser` instance to be doing all the work, initialize and close outside of your main loop. Right now, you're spawning a new `Browser` instance with every iteration of `emails.zip`, times every iteration of `email.each`, times the 5 iterations of your `while` loop. This is just ungainly, and may be screwing up your expected results. So just doing:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
5.times do
  ... loop code ...
end
browser.close
```

Will at least make whatever's happening under the hood clearer.

Comment: when I use browser.close in my script it stops it from running altogether

Comment: so the last part instead of browser.close i just log out of the site.

Comment: See my newest edit, you're definitely spawning tons of instances, which on my machine opened up tons of browser windows and shit got out of hand, quick. See if that helps.